# com.google.step_count.cumulative requires android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION

Tags: java, android, google-fit

I'm trying to retrieve BPM from google-fit API in android. but getting error com.google.step_count.cumulative requires android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
included permission also in manifest file
    
Code:

```
private void readDataFitnessHistory() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
    Log.d("Range Start", "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
    Log.d("Range End", "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();


    DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiClient, readRequest).await(0, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    DataSet dataSet = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM);
    showDataSet(dataSet);
    displayBpmDataForToday();
}
private void showDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
    Log.e("History", "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
    DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
    DateFormat timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();

    for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
        Log.e("History", "Data point:");
        Log.e("History", "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
        Log.e("History", "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) + " " + timeFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
        Log.e("History", "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) + " " + timeFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
        for(Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
            Log.e("History", "\tField: " + field.getName() + " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
        }
    }
}
private void displayBpmDataForToday() {
    DailyTotalResult result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal( mGoogleApiClient, DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM ).await(0, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    showDataSet(result.getTotal());
}
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" /> included permission

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 introduces the **android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION** runtime permission for apps that need to detect the user's step count or classify the user's physical activity, such as walking, biking, or moving in a vehicle. This is designed to give users visibility of how device sensor data is used in Settings.

Add Permission in Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

Ask for Runtime Permission:

```
//Run time Permissions
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                    Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
            };

     if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            PERMISSIONS,
                            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION);
                }
```